# How to fix this package deployment problem?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hi I have an SSIS package deployed on the server. I changed some thing on the package in the BI studio, compiled and deployed on the server. But, the changes are not being reflected on the server.

What I observed is that, when I open the deployed dtsx files (old and new ) in BI studio, they both are having the same MajorVersion, Minor version and versionbuild number. Is this creating a problem for me? Is not installing the new package assuming it is the same version file and not updating on the server?

Comment: possible duplicate of [updates to SSIS packages not reflecting on the server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724975/updates-to-ssis-packages-not-reflecting-on-the-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working a lot on this issue, tI found the solution :

Check if the package is already installed on the server by running the query on the server (you must have proper previliges to run select on msdb). Select * From msdb.dbo.sysssispackagefolders

Solution 1: If it is already installed, just delete that particular package from this table. Then, try to install. It works.

Solution 2: While you edit the package in the Buisiness Intelligence studio, I observed that the Major version, Minor version and BuildVersion are not changing even if I compile the total package. Because of it, when I install it on the server, it is assuming that this version has already been installed, so, not updating the package on the server. So, If we change atleast the version build number of the package manually in BI studio and built it, and then install it on the server. It worked.